# Making a Unity Mobile Game with Google Firestore (Plus Google Stack) Across iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I want to start developing a unity mobile game that will use Google Firestore as its database and ideally cloud functions for its "server architecture." I have experience with Firebase and Unity but what I am confused about is two things:

1. What exactly is Google's "Full Stack", like what should I be using on top of Firestore and maybe cloud functions (is this all I need to worry about, or is there more, working with AWS at work there seems to be a ton of things that need to be in place for a well working project)
2. What is the best way to integrate Firestore with a Unity Mobile game that spans across iOS and Android? Is there a tutorial to get started with a project like this?

Thanks a lot guys, and I would also appreciate any other tips on how I should approach making a unity mobile game that spans across iOS/Android. For instance what other technologies should I be looking to integrate?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that "Full Stack" includes all of Firebase's other services: Authentication, Cloud Functions, ML Kit, Hosting, Cloud Storage, Realtime Database, and Firestore (https://firebase.google.com/products/).

Firestore is currently not available for Unity (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dc8CuW7LDM4). You could write a bridge for it but that would be a lot of work and hard to test.

The Realtime Database may meet most of your needs though. It is the current version of what the Firestore is.

Answer (score 1):

Update to this question:

Firestore SDK for Unity is currently in alpha (since 5th of march).
[Link to the Github discussion.](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/381)

In case it is changed here is the announcement:

> As some of you have noticed, yesterday we released Firebase Unity SDK
> 6.12.0 which includes an alpha release of Firestore. This release is experimental:
>
> We expect there will be breaking changes to the API Some features are
> missing (for example: IN queries) You may uncover issues for which we
> can't supply an immediate resolution Please try it out and let us know
> how it goes. Read more about how to get this release in Add Firebase
> to your Unity project.
>
> We're very excited to (finally) get this in your hands and hear how it
> works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I love Firebase (/Firestore) and we use it all the time for major projects for clients.

But Firebase is "totally useless" for certain things...

Just forget about it for "multiplayer games with Unity."

Suggest you

1. Familiarize yourself with Playfab, do some small demos.
2. Don't forget that Unity itself offers multiplayer inherently built-in to Unity.  (Indeed, it is of course a major part of Unity, it is a mammoth achievement.)  Unity multiplayer is not perfect but you should certainly familiarize yourself with it totally, including the sundry cloud features, before exploring other paths.

Firebase is useless for Unity mp games, set it aside.

> how I should approach making a unity mobile game that spans across iOS/Android

**There are 100,000 ? such games which are done, naturally, just with Unity's own MP systems.**

How else? As I say, once you are very familiar with that, also explore Playfab.